# Solr can't find schema.xml

Tags: java, solr

My client application finds my Solr 4.2.1 server and seems to be able to index documents. I haven't written any query code yet. But when I access my Solr Admin backoffice, when I click on query, I get the following exception:

```
Apr 16, 2013 4:55:31 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [1050] webapp=/viparis-solr-server path=/admin/file params={file=/usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/viparis-solr-server/Proto/solr/common/fr/schema.xml&contentType=text/xml;charset%3Dutf-8} status=500 QTime=27
Apr 16, 2013 4:55:31 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: null:java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ShowFileRequestHandler.showFromFileSystem(ShowFileRequestHandler.java:212)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ShowFileRequestHandler.handleRequestBody(ShowFileRequestHandler.java:122)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1816)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:448)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

As a matter of fact, the file `/usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/viparis-solr-server/Proto/solr/common/fr/schema.xml` exists, and the Tomcat server has reading rights to access it. This path is defined in the solr.xml as part of the core configuration.

Any idea?

**Edit:**
After Arkain's suggestion, here is a piece of my schema.xml. It's actually the only part I changed after I took it from another properly working Solr server, so maybe the problem is located in there:

```
    <field name="TYPE" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="id_manifestation" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="nom" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="false"/>
    <field name="nomFr" type="text_full" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
    <field name="nomEn" type="text_full" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
    <field name="theme" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="descriptionEn" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="descriptionFr" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="motsCleEn" type="text_full" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="motsCleFr" type="text_full" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="dateDebut" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="dateFin" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="url" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
    <field name="logo" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
```

**Edit:**
Here my solrconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<!--
 This is a stripped down config file used for a simple example...  
 It is *not* a good example to work from. 
-->
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_41</luceneMatchVersion>
  <!--  The DirectoryFactory to use for indexes.
        solr.StandardDirectoryFactory, the default, is filesystem based.
        solr.RAMDirectoryFactory is memory based, not persistent, and doesn't work with replication. -->
  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.StandardDirectoryFactory}"/>

  <dataDir>${solr.core1.data.dir:}</dataDir>

  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
<!--     <updateLog> -->
<!--       <str name="dir">${solr.core1.data.dir:}</str> -->
<!--     </updateLog> -->
  </updateHandler>

  <!-- realtime get handler, guaranteed to return the latest stored fields 
    of any document, without the need to commit or open a new searcher. The current 
    implementation relies on the updateLog feature being enabled. -->
  <requestHandler name="/get" class="solr.RealTimeGetHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="omitHeader">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

 <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" startup="lazy" /> 

  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="true" >
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="false" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048" formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048" />
  </requestDispatcher>

  <requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true" />
  <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" startup="lazy" class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />
  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler"  />
  <requestHandler name="/admin/" class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.AdminHandlers" />

  <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
<!--    <fragmentsBuilder name="colored" class="org.apache.solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder"> -->
<!--      <lst name="defaults"> -->
<!--        <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[ -->
<!--             <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">, -->
<!--             <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">, -->
<!--             <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">, -->
<!--             <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">, -->
<!--             <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str> -->
<!--        <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str> -->
<!--      </lst> -->
<!--    </fragmentsBuilder> -->

   <!-- Spell Check

        The spell check component can return a list of alternative spelling
        suggestions.  

        http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent
     -->
  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>


    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">default</str>
        <str name="field">textng</str>
        <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">spellchecker</str>
        <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
        <str name="comparatorClass">score</str>
    </lst>

<!--<lst name="spellchecker">-->
<!--    <str name="name">suggest</str>-->
<!--    <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>-->
<!--    <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>-->
<!--    -->
<!--    <str name="field">textng</str>   the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
<!--    <float name="threshold">0.005</float>-->
<!--    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>-->
<!--</lst>-->
  </searchComponent>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the spellcheck component.  

       NOTE: This is purely as an example.  The whole purpose of the
       SpellCheckComponent is to hook it into the request handler that
       handles your normal user queries so that a separate request is
       not needed to get suggestions.

       IN OTHER WORDS, THERE IS REALLY GOOD CHANCE THE SETUP BELOW IS
       NOT WHAT YOU WANT FOR YOUR PRODUCTION SYSTEM!

       See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent for details
       on the request parameters.
    -->
  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="df">textng</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">10</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="rows">100</str>
        <str name="fl">*,score</str>
        <str name="qf">textng^100</str>
        <str name="sort">TYPE asc, score desc</str>
        <str name="pf">textng^100</str>
        <double name="typeboost">1.0</double>
        <str name="debugQuery">false</str>

        <str name="facet">on</str>
        <str name="facet.field">nom_manifestation</str>
        <str name="facet.limit">-1</str>
        <str name="hl.highlightMultiTerm">true</str>
        <str name="hl.fragsize">200</str>
        <str name="hl.snippets">200</str>
<!--        <str name="hl.fragmentsBuilder">colored</str> -->
<!--        <str name="hl.fragListBuilder">simple</str> -->
        <str name="hl.fl">*</str>
        <str name="hl.usePhraseHighlighter">true</str>
        <str name="hl">true</str>

    </lst>
    <arr name="first-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>

<requestHandler name="/selectItem" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="df">nom</str>
        <str name="rows">100</str>
        <str name="fl">*,score</str>
        <str name="qf">nom^100</str>
        <str name="sort">TYPE asc, score desc</str>
        <double name="typeboost">1.0</double>
        <str name="debugQuery">false</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>

<requestHandler name="/store" class="solr.SearchHandler"
    startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="df">nom</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="rows">100</str>
        <str name="sort">score desc</str>
        <double name="typeboost">1.0</double>
        <str name="debugQuery">false</str>
        <str name="qf">nom^100 textphon^50</str>
        <str name="facet">on</str>
        <str name="facet.field">nom_manifestation</str>
        <str name="facet.limit">-1</str>
        <str name="hl.highlightMultiTerm">true</str>
        <str name="hl.fragsize">200</str>
        <str name="hl.snippets">200</str>
<!--        <str name="hl.fragmentsBuilder">colored</str> -->
<!--        <str name="hl.fragListBuilder">simple</str> -->
        <str name="hl.fl">*</str>
        <str name="hl.usePhraseHighlighter">true</str>
        <str name="hl">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>

  <searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">suggest</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
      <!-- Alternatives to lookupImpl: 
           org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.FSTLookup   [finite state automaton]
           org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.WFSTLookupFactory [weighted finite state automaton]
           org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.jaspell.JaspellLookup [default, jaspell-based]
           org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup   [ternary trees]
      -->
      <str name="field">textng</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
      <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
      <!--str name="buildOnCommit">true</str-->
<!--
      <str name="sourceLocation">american-english</str>
-->
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <!-- config for the admin interface --> 
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>solr</defaultQuery>
  </admin>

</config>
```

Comment: It seems like it can find the file, it's a error code 500, which is typically (in the http world) a server error. Maybe there is an error in the schema.xml that causes it to fail during initialization

Comment: @arkain: good idea! I added a piece of my schema.xml to the question...

Comment: I don't see any obvious syntax errors. Double check that all the types are defined correctly. Make sure there are no xml errors. If everything else fails, try to change the schema to contain only a single field of type string or something, and remove all `FieldTypes` that aren't used, just to reduce the number of places things can go wrong.

Comment: What I really don't understand is that the indexing seems to work, when I start my server, I see the server loading the different cores, with schemas and it seems pretty good to me. But in the admin console I get an exception. Weird...

Comment: There is no error when the Tomcat server starts up.

Comment: Try to distill is to the simplest possible config, and gradually work form there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure there are no other errors when you startup solr? Solr reads `solr.xml`, `solrconfig.xml` and the `schema.xml` at boot time, if anything is odd with these files, there should be an other error in your logs. Can you restart the server just to be sure?

One thing I could think of would be default values in `solrconfig.xml`, but the error message would be different. I noticed in the schema you postet that there is no field named **content**. However, this field is used in the solr-home skeleton. Check for constructs like this in your solrconfig.xml

```
 <lst name="defaults">
   // more defaults
   <str name="df">content</str>
 </lst>
```

If this is the case, there should be a warning at startup. This would explain, why indexing works (you dont't rely on defaults there) but querying fails.

An other thought. Have you hardened your Servlet Container in any way? Solr uses `getClassLoader().getResource()` a lot to find files. But there should be more errors if this is the case.

Can your view your schema in your browser (Select the core from the dropdown, than *Schema*)?

Comment: I can't view my schema in the admin console, that's the whole problem. Everything else seems to work fine. I get the indicated exception when I click on Schema in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `tpl` directory was missing for some reason from my Solr server installation.

I checked out and made a copy of an existing and working Solr server used in our company. So something is probably missing in the project repository on our source control system.